# Updating A selected Task on the change of a Task

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on a react native project. It is sort of like a Todo list but not exactly my problem is I have two variables which are actually my data I know not a good idea I will change it later, but this is how the two variables are:

```
 // const all of the tasks to do
 const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
 // const all the selected Tasks
 const [selectedTasks, setSelectedTasks] = useState([]);
```

Now Each Item of the tasks Variable is going to be like this:

```
 {
   key: tasks.length + tasksNewName,
   taskName: taskNameInputText,
   usedUp: false
 }
```

And Each Item of the selected Tasks Variable is going to be like this:

```
 {
   id: selectedTasks.length,
   taskName: tasks[key].taskName,
   tasksKey: tasks[key].key
 }
```

So as you can see they are 2D arrays where each element is a dictionary but as you can also see the selected task contains a piece of memory from the task that it was selected from now however the problem I am phasing is that whenever I change a task name basically updated it I wish that its selected counterparts name change too.

Here is the code I need to change:

```
const updateSelectedTasks = (tasksId) => {
  // Here is the new Code
}
```

The task id parameter is holding that changed tasks Id now can someone please tell me a way to solve this.

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 0):

you can keep all tasks here and add one more field isSelected inside the task object

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

so it will look like this

```
 {
   key: tasks.length + tasksNewName,
   taskName: taskNameInputText,
   usedUp: false,
   isSelected: true
 }
```

I think you don't need this line

`const [selectedTasks, setSelectedTasks] = useState([]);`

```
const updateSelectedTasks = (taskId, taskName) => {

    tasks.forEach((item) => {
      if(item.id === taskId) {
         item.name = taskName
      }
    }

}
```

In case you need two states, you need to do something like this

```
const updateSelectedTasks = (taskId, taskName) => {

    tasks.forEach((item) => {
      if(item.id === taskId) {
         item.name = taskName
      }
    }

    selectedTasks.forEach((item) => {
      if(item.id === taskId) {
         item.name = taskName
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting thanks for the answer I will try it but in the meantime in my case is there a way to make that function change the name when I have 2 states because I feel it is better for me to keep these separated. But maybe your's might be better so I will try it.

Comment: in any case, it will be better to not keep duplicated items. 
in case you need to keep two states 
you need to have 2 forEach or for looks inside your update function

Comment: Actually the task is already updated I just want to update the selected task counterpart but nice solution will try both

Comment: Thank you @NverAbgaryan Th second solution worked like a charm